# Setting Gtalk Status with Jabber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xmpp, google-talk, xmpp4r

I'm using Jabber to communicate with gTalk server. Right now, I'm able to connect properly. Also, I can send/receive messages. But, I'm unable to set my gtalk presence as busy though `jabber.status` method

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xmpp4r-simple'

include Jabber
#Jabber::debug = true

jid = 'user@gmail.com'
pass = 'password'

jabber = Simple.new(jid, pass)
jabber.status(:dnd, 'password')  
jabber.deliver('user2@gmail.com','away')
```

Can you suggest where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That should work, but note that

```
jabber.status(:dnd, 'password')
```

will set your status to password, which is a bad idea.

Are you sure you're logged on initially? If so:

```
jabber.connected?
```

should return true.